# numpy.any() returns True but "is True" comparison fails

Tags: python, numpy

If `numpy.any()` returns `True` the comparison with `is True` fails but with `== True` works. Does anyone know why?

A minimal example

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy

a = numpy.array([True])

if a.any() == True:
  print('== works')

if a.any() is True:
  print('is works')
```

The output of this code is just `== works`.

Comment: Why are you using `is` for this comparison anyway? [In this context `==` is the semantically correct comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: For the same reason `1 == 1.0` is `True` and  `1 is 1.0` is `False`.  1 is an integer, 1.0 is a float.  Two things can be equivalent while having different underlying structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`numpy` has it's own booleans, `numpy.True_` and `numpy.False_` that have different identities from Python's native booleans. Anyway, you should be using `==` for such equity comparisons

```
>>> a.any() is True
False
>>> a.any() is numpy.True_
True
>>> True is numpy.True_
False
>>> True == numpy.True_
True
```

Comment: Actually, don’t check for boolean equality at all. Just do `if a.any()` or `if not a.any()`.

Comment: @poke timgeb Yes agreed of course, in this specific boolean context, I meant in general that equity checks are preferable to identity ones (unless you're actually trying to check the identity of course)

Answer (score 3):

The types of the returns are different:

```
>>> type(a.any())
<type 'numpy.bool_'>
>>> type(True)
<type 'bool'>
```

So, a.any() isn't `True` as such, it's only equal to `True`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `a.any()` does not return the standard Python `True` (an instance of the class `bool`).

```
>>> type(a.any())
<type 'numpy.bool_'>
```

So in short, numpy has its own True-value, but when you print it, it looks just like Python's built in `True`.

Comment: Thanks, this is it! I should have checked the type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) returns a `numpy.bool_` which is a [different datatype](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) used by numpy.

So you cannot compare a `numpy.bool_` with a Python `bool` using an identity check. You would have to use numpy’s `true` then: `numpy.True_`

```
>>> a.any() is numpy.True_
True
```

The main reason why they aren’t using Python’s `bool` is because `numpy.bool_` is just a single byte whereas a Python `bool` is based on the Python `int` which will always be more expensive.

Comment: `numpy` also has `numpy.bool`, which `is` Python's native `bool`, legacy creates some odd things I guess